# the optional image is not showing in my table

Tags: image, datatable, yajra-datatable

the following include 3 folder of codes which are controller, product blade and create new product blade. I check from database, the optional images has been recorded in my database but they cannot be show in the product table.

controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Validate the request data
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'products_title' => 'required',
        'products_image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'products_optional_images.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'products_desc' => 'required',
        'products_price' => 'required|numeric',
        'products_qty' => 'required|numeric',
    ]);
    
    // Handle the image upload for the main image
    $imageName = '';
    if ($request->hasFile('products_image')) {
        $image = $request->file('products_image');
        $imageName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
    }

    // Create a new product
    $product = new Product;
    $product->title = $request->input('products_title');
    $product->image = $imageName; // Use $imageName instead of $ImageName
    $product->desc = $request->input('products_desc');
    $product->price = $request->input('products_price');
    $product->qty = $request->input('products_qty');
    $product->save();

    // Handle optional images upload
    if ($request->hasFile('products_optional_images')) {
        $optionalImages = $request->file('products_optional_images');
        foreach ($optionalImages as $optionalImage) {
            $optionalImageName = time() . '_' . $optionalImage->getClientOriginalName();
            $optionalImage->move(public_path('images'), $optionalImageName);
            $image = new Image();
            $image->filename = $optionalImageName;
            $image->product_id = $product->id;
            $image->save();
        }
    }

    return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('success', 'Product created successfully.');
}
```

product blade

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <h3><strong>Admin View -- Product Database</strong></h3>
                    <a class="logout-btn" href="/admin/logout">Logout</a>
                    <a class="admin-btn" href="/admin">User Database</a>
                    <a class="add-btn" href="/products/create">Add new Product</a>
                </div>
            </div>
                <table class="table table-bordered data-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Image</th>
                            <th>Optional Image</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th width="100px">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($products as $product)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $product->title }}</td>
                            <td>
                                @if($product->image)
                                <img src="{{ asset('images/'.$product->image) }}" alt="{{ $product->title }}" width="100">
                                @endif
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @foreach($product->optionalImages as $image)
                                <img src="{{ asset('images/'.$image->filename) }}" alt="{{ $product->title }}" width="100">
                                @endforeach
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ $product->desc }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $product->price }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $product->qty }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="btn-edit" href="{{ route('products.edit', $product->id) }}">Edit</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "/products", // Replace with the correct route URL
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            columns: [
                { data: 'title', name: 'title' },
                { data: 'image', name: 'image',
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        if (data) {
                            return '<img src="/images/' + data + '" alt="' + row.title + '" width="100">';
                        } else {
                            return '';
                        }
                    }
                },
                { data: 'optional_images', name: 'optional_images',
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        var images = '';
                        if (data && data.length > 0) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                images += '<img src="/images/' + data[i].filename + '" alt="' + row.title + '" width="100">';
                            }
                        }
                        return images;
                    }
                },
                { data: 'desc', name: 'desc' },
                { data: 'price', name: 'price',
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return 'RM ' + data;
                    }
                },
                { data: 'qty', name: 'qty' },
                {
                    data: 'action',
                    name: 'action',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false,
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        var editUrl = "{{ route('products.edit', ':id') }}";
                        editUrl = editUrl.replace(':id', row.id);
                        return '<a class="btn-edit" href="' + editUrl + '">Edit</a>';
                    }
                },
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

create product blade

```
<form action="{{ route('products.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="createProductForm">
    @csrf
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="products_title" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Image</td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="products_image" multiple/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Optional Image</td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="products_optional_images[]" multiple>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>
                <textarea name="products_desc"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="products_price" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="products_qty" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="ADD new Product" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(document).on("submit", "#handleAjax", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent reload

            var $submitButton = $(this).find("[type='submit']");
            $submitButton.html("Create...");

            $.ajax({
                url: $("#handleAjax").attr('action'),
                method: $("#handleAjax").attr('method'),
                data: new FormData(this),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        // Redirect to the success URL
                        if (response.success_redirect) {
                            window.location.href = response.success_redirect;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Handle any errors or display appropriate messages
                        console.log(response.error);
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                },
                complete: function() {
                        $submitButton.val("Submit"); // Revert submit button text
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is all the code i using, i check my database, and it shows those optional image has been recorded too in my database, but it cannot be show, why??